# Subsurf, triangulate and UV texture problem

Tags: uv

I am using triangulate and next subsurf modifier on my tent project. I have huge problem with UV mapping.
[image: With triangulate and subsurf.]

Without triangulate it is porblem too, there are any freak "faces" under model, I don't know why:
[image: Without triangulate, subsurf only.]

Do You have any idea how to solve this problem?

I tried make subdivisions in edit mode, also making offset near edges. There is less errors but it still looks horrible but UV map is a lot of worse (I need UV for walls with "sample text" to be this "cuted triangle" like it is now).

Thanks,
A.

---

Blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sb70islclejgmys/Tent_0.22.blend?dl=0

The mesh is the simplest as it can. It is surprise for me that sometimes it is no problem to texture complex mesh but with this simple mesh it is a problem. Maybe I am using wrong technique?

Comment: Most likely the "freak" faces you point out occur because Blender splits non-planar quads/Ngons placed there. The solution would be to redo that part of mesh with cleaner topology. Add screenshot of the mesh while in Edit mode with all selected and UV/Image Editor opened for UV  map to be visible.

Answer (score 1):

Blender doesn't subsurf n-gons or triangles that well. Try retopologizing the mesh, and then applyong the subsurf and triangulate modifiers and UV them after that (you can duplicate the mesh before you apply the modifiers so you have a backup)